# Reducing a String to array on Fixed length in Dataweave 2.0

Tags: arrays, loops, reduce, dataweave, mule4

Hello guys i'm looking for a solution or ideas to the problem in data weave 2.0 Logic

problem is to convert an string to multiple arrays if the string crosses the max length

max length is 8

```
{"message" : "hello this is Muley"}

expected output is 
{
 "message": ["hello", "this is", "muley"]
}
```

i have tried the map and temporary variable to store the values but it was giving an null array

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
var tmp=[[]]
var max=8
fun ck(tmp,data)= 
    (
    if(sizeOf((tmp[-1] joinBy (" ")  default "")++ " " ++ data) <= max ) 
       (tmp[-1] << data) 
    else 
        tmp << [data]
    )
var msd=(payload.message splitBy(" ") map(item, value) -> (ck(tmp, item)))
---
{"message": tmp map()-> $ joinBy  " "}
```

output is

```
{
    "message": [ "" ]
}
```

Comment: Would the expected output be 
{
 "message": ["hello", "this is", "muley"]
} 
or
{
 "message": ["hello", "this", "is", "muley"]
}

Comment: excepted is { "message": ["hello", "this is", "muley"] }  because "this is" length is less than 8


if i want  { "message": ["hello", "this", "is", "muley"] } i can simply use {message: payload.message splitBy(" ")}

Comment: So you want to take as many substrings at a time while the size of that group is less than max (8 in this case) and you want to spit out the output as an Array.

Comment: yes so that every array element will be printed in new line in output

Answer (score 1):

It is somewhat complex because of the condition on spaces. I have tried to encapsulate that into functions for clarity.

```js
%dw 2.0
output application/json
import * from dw::core::Strings
import * from dw::core::Arrays
fun findNextSpace(s, max)=do {
    var spaces = find(s, " ")
    var overIndex=spaces indexWhere ($ > max - 1)
    var firstSpaceBeforeMax = spaces[if (overIndex > 0) (overIndex  - 1) else -1]
    ---
    firstSpaceBeforeMax
}

fun splitMax(data, max)= 
    if (sizeOf(data) >= max)
        flatten([data[0 to findNextSpace(data, max) - 1],splitMax(data[findNextSpace(data, max) + 1 to -1], max) ])  
    else
        data
---
{
    message: splitMax(payload.message, 8)
}
```

I'm not sure if you are aware that DataWeave is a functional language where variables are immutable. It is not possible to modify a 'temporary' variable, only to return new values. I used a recursive function to achieve the result.

Answer (score 0):

```
%dw 2.0
fun strtoarr(string :String  ,cap:Number)=do
{
    var size=sizeOf(string)
    var ind=(
        if(size >= cap) 
            (
            if((string[0 to cap] lastIndexOf(" ")) == -1) 
                (string indexOf(" "))
            else 
                (string[0 to cap] lastIndexOf (" "))
            )
        else 
            size
        ) -1
    var str=string[0 to ind]
---
flatten([str] ++ (if(size > cap) strtoarr(string[ind+2 to -1],cap) else []) )
}
---
strtoarr("hello this is Muley",8)
```

thanks to [@aled](https://stackoverflow.com/users/721855/aled) for suggesting the recursion and new trick in DW